# Show that ((p → q ) ∧ ~q) →~p is a taugtology using logical equivalance

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a doubt in the last step of the solution of above question
((p → q ) ∧ ~q) →~p

Now

1. Step 1: ((p → q ) ∧ ~q) →~p ≡ ((~p ∨ q ) ∧ ~q) →~p, using
   symmetricity of  ≡
2. Step 2 : ≡ ((~p∧ ~q) ∨ (q ∧ ~q)) →~p, using De Morgan law
3. Step 3 : ≡ ((~p∧ ~q) ∨ F) →~p, since (q ∧ ~q) is always false
4. Step 4 : ≡(~p∧ ~q) →~p , using p ∨ F ≡ p
5. Step 5 : (~p∧ ~q) →~p which is a tautology

Here my doubt comes, how come it is proved that (~p∧ ~q) →~p is a tautology, by which law? because we should not use truth table to prove it.

Please clarify, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\neg p \land \neg q)\rightarrow \neg p \equiv \neg p \lor \neg(\neg p \land \neg q) \equiv \neg p \lor p \lor q\equiv \top \lor q \equiv \top$

From an intuitive standpoint, note that if the first conjunction is true, then $\neg p$ must also be true, because a conjunction of statements is only true if both statements are true individually.

Comment: So (¬p∧¬q)→¬p≡¬p∨¬(¬p∧¬q) is derived from  p → q ≡ ¬p ∨ q, which i used in step 1, right ?, thank you very much,  eyeballfrog

Comment: @Silvestor Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ eyeballfrog, Also your intuitive standpoint is very helpful